CephFS snapshot mirroring: how does the snapshot sizes inside .snap work exactly?
we're currently experimenting with CephFS snapshot mirroring to evaluate whether it will serve our purposes of establishing a passive storage backup to a secondary site. We setup two CEPH clusters using CEPH Reef version 18.2.2 with 3 nodes each having a boot disk and an additional 256 GBs disks for the OSDs totaling 768 GBs per cluster, then we established an Erasure Code pool for the CephFS data with k = 2 and m = 1 as well as a replicated pool for the metadata. The CephFS was created on those two pools, and snapshots were enabled on it.
The next step was to create a snapshot schedule along with its retention policy (which was 24 snapshots with 1 hour between each one) and it worked perfectly after activation. We mounted the CephFS to one of our servers under a certain mount point/folder and we filled it with 45 GBs worth of files for our testing, then we waited for a day, which brings us to my question.
What I expected is that a snapshot should have the same size as the current filesystem (45 GBs) which is true after inspecting the .snap folder under the mount point, what I was not able to understand is that after 24 hours of snapshots, I had 1.1 TBs worth of data under .snap which did not make any sense since we only have 768 GBs in total, and even around two-thirds of that due to the Erasure Code profile, even though the "ceph status" command shows only 75 GBs of usage out of 768 (which appears to not account for snapshot sizes).
How is this possible? Am I missing something? Is this a fluke or is CEPH overwriting existing data? Because when I checked, the original files were intact and not corrupt, also the mirroring functionality was working perfectly having my files copied to the second cluster. Shouldn't the snapshot schedule stop when the .snap folder size exceeds the total available disk space? Your insight and knowledge are crucial as the documentation does not mention details about how this practically works.

I don't know how you measured the size of the .snap folder but this does not make sense. Snapshots are not copies.
